# Can we measure temperature in an isothermal Universe?

Tags: cosmology, temperature, space-expansion, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

It is envisaged that ,in the future ,Universe can end in a [big freeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe#:%7E:text=Big%20Freeze%20or%20Heat%20Death,-Main%20articles%3A%20Future&text=The%20heat%20death%20of%20the,asymptotically%20approaches%20absolute%20zero%20temperature.), where there will be no energy gradient. It is also theorised that Universe was [isothermal](https://www.theochem.ru.nl/%7Epwormer/Knowino/knowino.org/wiki/Big_Bang.html#:%7E:text=Essentially%20the%20period%20just%20prior,CMB%20spectrum%20is%20blackbody%20spectrum.)(with some irregularities I guess) in the beginning.
Also , CMB is almost constant in every direction suggesting almost same temperature in every direction.

However , I have a doubt regarding a situation in which whole Universe (in big or small size) is isothermal with no irregularities.

Suppose , Universe is isothermal , that is , it has same temperature in every direction then is it possible to measure the temperature? ( There is no temperature gradient) In other words, is it possible ,in principle, to envisage an experiment ,in an exactly isothermal universe ,to measure the temperature of Universe?

Comment: Aside the question of how to power any equipment, yes. A thermocouple would do just fine.

Comment: @JonCuster In a thermocouple the junctions must be at different temperatures …if the temperature difference is zero then there will be no emf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording an experimental result generates entropy. In a perfectly isothermal universe at maximum entropy, this is impossible. Thus no experiment of *any* kind is theoretically possible in such a hypothetical situation. Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 1):

If by "isothermal universe" you mean the state like in the "heat death of the universe", then no, because there is no thermometer, only chaotic, feature-less, gas-like system. But heat death of our universe is quite a speculative and problematic idea, because the whole universe isn't a gas in a box. Real universe we observe isn't in any recognizable state of thermodynamic equilibrium, and it is not clear it even can be, because of its unknown boundaries, matter being very rarified, and the dominant role of gravity.

If you mean the more realistic thing, that a region of universe is close to the state of thermodynamic equilibrium, and thus has the same temperature everywhere, then yes - if temperature is in measurable range of e.g. a mercury thermometer, then such device in that region will eventually get into equilibrium with the region, and will show its temperature.